# Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

/// Global Variables
HANDLE ConsoleHandle;

int RGB (int R, int G, int B); // line 8
int Set_Color (int RGB_Fore, int RGB_Back);

int main (void)
{
  // Get Handle
  ConsoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
  char Str [32] = "Happy New Year.\n";
  printf("%s", Str);
  system("pause>nul");
  return 0;
}

int RGB (int R, int G, int B) // line 21
{
  return (R*4 + G*2 + B);
}

int Set_Color (int RGB_Fore, int RGB_Back)
{
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(ConsoleHandle, RGB_Fore*8 + RGB_Back);
}
```

The TDM-GCC reported:

```
| line | Message
|  08  | error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
|  21  | error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
```

Why? How to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `%s` if you just print a constant string anyway? And where is Line 8, 21?

Comment: Shot in the dark: I assume one of the headers you included contains a definement for `RGB`. Rename the function and see if that helps.

Comment: @Devolus because it's a snippet?

Comment: Looks like RGB is a type or macro trying to find more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [RGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a macro, if you rename the function that error will go away. Also `Set_Color` needs to return a value you have it defined to return an `int` but you fall of the end of the function without returning anything.

If you attempted to use the value of `Set_Color` without an explicit return that would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per the C99 draft standard section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12*:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

and this is *undefined* in *C++* regardless of whether you attempt to use the return value or not.

Comment: Can I use `#undef` in this case?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia that does not sound like a good idea to me, just rename your function most editors will allow you to do this quickly if you have that name all over the place.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia: It's generally best not to fight the system, so renaming the function is easiest and best.  If the macro is a function-like macro (it must be one that takes 3 arguments if it is), then you can evade/avoid it by using `int (RGB)(int R, int G, int B);` and similarly wrapping the function name in parentheses every time you reference (or define) it.  That gets to be old quickly, hence the "don't fight the system" advice. The difficulty is knowing all the possible names that are in the Windows header.